# User input in Python, after a false statement and recall the function to force the correct entry, the true statement doesn't do what it should do

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

It is my second question here in the group, I really tried to find the answer everywhere, probably I used the wrong terms when looking for it. I am a completely new in Python. Please, tell me If the answer is available in your community or in anywhere else, and I will delete this post. Thank you.

So, I am doing a Python online course, and in the assignment I have to create a database for a movie store, so I have to create menus and actions like, view the list of movies, add a movie, search a movie, delete a movie and so on...

I am stuck in the process to add a movie, that is when I ask the user to insert the correct 'movie year' in format '2018' and the correct category (which is a dictionary)...

The problem is, if the users do their job correctly since begin, everything perfectly works, i.e. the true statements in the IF's and the Try(Except) work great, but when the users input a wrong format either in the 'movie year' or a different number for the category in the category movie, the IF's and Try(Except) FALSE statements work and make the users insert their answer again, however, the new TRUE statements don't do what they should do, which are to 'return' (capture) the user input, it is returning 'None' instead.

Please, help me out with this.

Thank you.

By the way, I am coding in PyCharm, if that matters. Cheers.

#### Assignment 1 - Database for a movie store

```
def save_dict_to_file(dic):
    f = open('dict.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(dic))
    f.close()


def load_dict_from_file():
    f = open('dict.txt', 'r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return eval(data)


def open_or_loading():

    print('\n\nHello to Movies.base\n\n'
          'Do you want to load an existent database or create a new one?\n\n'
          'Choose 1 for loading an existent.\n'
          'Choose 2 for create a new database.\n')
    user_answer = input('Option: ')

    if user_answer == '1':
        database = load_dict_from_file()

    elif user_answer == '2':
        database = {}
        save_dict_to_file(database)
    else:
        print('Wrong option, try again.\n')
        open_or_loading()


    def view_all_list():
        for key, value in database.items():
            print(key, value)



    def add_movie():

        last_inserted = (len(database))
        movie_name = input('What is the name of the movie: ')

        def year_movie():
            try:
                movie_year = int(input('Released in year: '))
            except:
                print('You must insert a year format: e.g.: 2018')
                year_movie()
            else:
                if movie_year < 1000 or movie_year > 9999:
                    print('You must insert a year format: e.g.: 2018')
                    year_movie()
                else:
                    return movie_year
        movie_year = year_movie()
        movie_director = input('Directed by: ')

        def category_movie():

            print('Choose one category:\n\n'
                  '1 - Action\n'
                  '2 - Adventure\n'
                  '3 - Avant-garde / Experimental\n'
                  '4 - Comedy\n'
                  '5 - Comedy-Drama\n'
                  '6 - Crime\n'
                  '7 - Drama\n'
                  '8 - Epic\n'
                  '9 - Family-Children\n'
                  '10 - Fantasy\n'
                  '11 - Historical-Film\n'
                  '12 - Horror\n'
                  '13 - Musical\n'
                  '14 - Mystery\n'
                  '15 - Romance\n'
                  '16 - Sci-Fi / Science-Fiction\n'
                  '17 - Spy Film\n'
                  '18 - Thriller\n'
                  '19 - War\n'
                  '20 - Western\n'
                  '21 - Adult\n')

            category = int(input('Category: '))

            def switch_demo(argument):
                switcher = {
                    1: 'Action',
                    2: 'Adventure',
                    3: 'Avant-garde / Experimental',
                    4: 'Comedy',
                    5: 'Comedy-Drama',
                    6: 'Crime',
                    7: 'Drama',
                    8: 'Epic',
                    9: 'Family-Children',
                    10: 'Fantasy',
                    11: 'Historical-Film',
                    12: 'Horror',
                    13: 'Musical',
                    14: 'Mystery',
                    15: 'Romance',
                    16: 'Sci-Fi / Science-Fiction',
                    17: 'Spy Film',
                    18: 'Thriller',
                    19: 'War',
                    20: 'Western',
                    21: 'Adult'
                }
                return switcher.get(category)

            if category < 1 or category > 21:
                print('\nInvalid Category\n')
                category_movie()
                switch_demo(category)

            else:
                return switch_demo(category)

        movie_category = category_movie()

        database[last_inserted + 1] = {}
        database[last_inserted + 1]['Movie Name'] = movie_name.upper()
        database[last_inserted + 1]['Movie Year'] = movie_year
        database[last_inserted + 1]['Director Name'] = movie_director.upper()
        database[last_inserted + 1]['Movie Category'] = movie_category

        save_dict_to_file(database)

        print(f'\nMovie {movie_name} added to database\n')

        menu_initial()


    def menu_initial():
        print('\n\nChose one option:\n\n'
              'Select 1 to view the movies list.\n'
              'Select 2 to add a new movie.\n'
              'Select 3 to find a movie.\n'
              'Select 4 to delete a movie.\n'
              'Select 5 to exit out\n')
        user_selection = (input('Option: '))

        if user_selection == '1':
            view_all_list()
            menu_initial()
        elif user_selection == '2':
            add_movie()
            menu_initial()
        elif user_selection == '3':
            print('Finding')
            menu_initial()
        elif user_selection == '4':
            print('deleting')
            menu_initial()
        elif user_selection == '5':
            print('Thanks for using Movie.Base. Bye-bye!')
            exit()
        else:
            print('Option do not exist')
            menu_initial()

    menu_initial()

open_or_loading()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method year_movie you need to always return something, otherwise you get `None`. You're calling this method recursively when the error is incorrect but you don't return the value. Try adding `return` keyword in the recursive calls:

```
    def year_movie():
        try:
            movie_year = int(input('Released in year: '))
        except:
            print('You must insert a year format: e.g.: 2018')
            return year_movie() ## return from recursive call
        else:
            if movie_year < 1000 or movie_year > 9999:
                print('You must insert a year format: e.g.: 2018')
                return year_movie() ## return from recursive call
            else:
                return movie_year
```

Also, in `category_movie()`:

```
        if category < 1 or category > 21:
            print('\nInvalid Category\n')
            category = category_movie()  # <-- Assign this value
            switch_demo(category)
```